# Could not access memory, Segmentation Fault

Tags: stl, stack, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement a Sierpinski Gasket using an iterative algorithm emulating the recursive version.

I am getting a segmentation fault. Probably the function is trying to dereference a NULL pointer, but I can't find it. The problem should be in the if block not in else. Because it is working fine if it skips the if block. Thanks for your help.

```
GLfloat points[18*(3^GENCOUNT)];

std::stack<Pyramid *> Q;

// initial Pyramid
Q.push(new Pyramid(Vec3(0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f),
                    Vec3(-0.4f, -0.4f, 0.4f),
                    Vec3(0.4f, -0.4f, 0.4f),
                    Vec3(0.4f, -0.4f, -0.4f),
                    Vec3(-0.4f, -0.4f, -0.4f), 0));

int i = 0;
while(!Q.empty())
{
    Pyramid *topPyr = Q.top();
    Q.pop();

    if(topPyr->mGeneration < GENCOUNT)
    {
        Vec3 baseVec3 = (((topPyr->mV2+topPyr->mV3)/2.0f) + ((topPyr->mV4+topPyr->mV5)/2.0f)) / 2.0f;

        Q.push(new Pyramid(topPyr->mV1,
                           (topPyr->mV1+topPyr->mV2)/2.0f,
                           (topPyr->mV1+topPyr->mV3)/2.0f,
                           (topPyr->mV1+topPyr->mV4)/2.0f,
                           (topPyr->mV1+topPyr->mV5)/2.0f, topPyr->mGeneration+1));
        Q.push(new Pyramid((topPyr->mV1+topPyr->mV2)/2.0f,
                           topPyr->mV2,
                           (topPyr->mV2+topPyr->mV3)/2.0f,
                           baseVec3,
                           (topPyr->mV2+topPyr->mV5)/2.0f, topPyr->mGeneration+1));
        Q.push(new Pyramid((topPyr->mV1+topPyr->mV3)/2.0f,
                           (topPyr->mV2+topPyr->mV3)/2.0f,
                           topPyr->mV3,
                           (topPyr->mV3+topPyr->mV4)/2.0f,
                           baseVec3, topPyr->mGeneration+1));
        Q.push(new Pyramid((topPyr->mV1+topPyr->mV4)/2.0f,
                           baseVec3,
                           (topPyr->mV3+topPyr->mV4)/2.0f,
                           topPyr->mV4,
                           (topPyr->mV4+topPyr->mV5)/2.0f, topPyr->mGeneration+1));
        Q.push(new Pyramid((topPyr->mV1+topPyr->mV5)/2.0f,
                           (topPyr->mV2+topPyr->mV5)/2.0f,
                           baseVec3,
                           (topPyr->mV4+topPyr->mV5)/2.0f,
                           topPyr->mV5, topPyr->mGeneration+1));
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV1.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;
        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV2.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;
        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV3.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;

        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV1.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;
        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV3.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;
        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV4.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;

        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV1.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;
        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV4.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;
        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV5.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;

        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV1.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;
        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV5.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;
        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV2.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;

        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV2.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;
        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV3.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;
        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV4.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;

        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV4.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;
        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV5.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;
        memcpy(points+i, topPyr->mV2.mVec3, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);i+=3;
    }
    delete topPyr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My C++ is very rusty, but assuming that no operator overloading is happening, doesn't

```
3^GENCOUNT
```

in your very first line mean "the bitwise XOR between 3 and GENCOUNT"? I'm pretty sure you meant that to be exponentiation, i.e. 3 to the power of GENCOUNT.